# AppServer Datasource Configuration at runtime - View or Update

Tags: datasource, jmx, informix, geronimo, appserver

We are using Geronimo application server and looking at options to view the data source configurations at runtime.

For example, if I have the following datasource configuration:

```
<connection-definition>
    <connectionfactory-interface>javax.sql.DataSource</connectionfactory-interface>
    <connectiondefinition-instance>
        <name>DB2_ds</name>
        <config-property-setting name="UserName">db2admin</config-property-setting>
        <config-property-setting name="DatabaseName">sample</config-property-setting>
        <config-property-setting name="Password">db2admin</config-property-setting>
        <config-property-setting name="ServerName">localhost</config-property-setting>
        <connectionmanager>
            <local-transaction/>
            <single-pool>
                <max-size>10</max-size>
                <min-size>0</min-size>
                <match-one/>
            </single-pool>
        </connectionmanager>
    </connectiondefinition-instance>
</connection-definition>
```

Is it possible to monitor the datasource configurations and attributes and runtime?
Is it possible to view and trace how database calls are made for attributes such as LockWait timeOut etc.

Do we need to implement mBeans to monitor the same?